# How to perform automated testing in Business Intelligent systems (BI)

Tags: automated-tests, birt, business-intelligence, talend

I'm currently working on a Business Intelligent(BI) system and now I want to create some automated tests if possible.

I have no idea how I can develop automated test on this BI project.
Has anyone experience on BI testing before?

I just need some idea for this testing.

Here is short description for my project.

1. My project will query data from any interested data source to our data source called ReportDB (MySql scheme) using talend as ETL tool
2. From ReportDB, I will export data to the following format as below

   - CSV file using Talend as a tool for exporting and summarizing data
   - Static Web using Eclipse BIRT as a tool for exporting and summarizing data

Answer (score 2):

I too am investigating something similar but for the MS stack.

Automated testing for BI systems seems to be a rather harder as code tends to be either more closed or harder to isolate.

Things we've done/investigated include:

- Move code to external units like DLLs and test them using test adaptors/harnesses
- Encode external rules into test harnesses test source and destination databases to catch things like rubbish data or invalid transformations
- Use model driven approaches to unify the building of common aspects - etls, tables, and cube structures, and to ensure they keep  integrity with tested patterns
- Use source control to keep control of live/test/development configurations and to add tests to verify that these are consistent to the approachs required.
- build reports out of common components by isolating queries producers and consumers

There's still lots to do and it's an evolutionary process.

Answer (score 0):

One way to automate the testing would be to use a black box approach and define a set of input records for which you have a defined set of expected outputs. Then each time a change is made to the ETL process you would validate that the expected outputs are maintained.

You could maintain either a test data source or a set of test csv files depending on what sort of input your process expects. With Talend you could use context variables to enable you to switch the source between production and test without recompiling the process.

To build your target outputs you could either do so by hand or you could run the process first on your test data and then inspect the outputs on a row-by-row basis to validate them.

You could then implement a fairly simple automated validation process to compare the output of a test run with the standard test result set. This would have to open both result sets and compare each row and column for equality.

This would add some overhead to your project as for each new column added to the process you would need to add that column to the test input and the automated validation. However you could argue that this additional overhead reduces the risk of a bug causing a data issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Selenium WebDriver to run integration tests on the static report pages. Have predefined data for your report. Run Eclipse birt and have selenium access the report in the browser. Write selenium tests to verify expected data exists on the page.